# webhdfs sensor-Airflow

Tags: airflow, sensors, webhdfs

I want to use sensors to check the arrival of files in hdfs.
I used **hdfs sensor** but I was not able to install snakebite as it required python2 and I'm running on python3.
As an alternative I am using **webhdfs sensor**.
While I'm trying to implement I'm getting below error

```
ERROR - b'<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>\n<title>Error 401 Authentication required</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /webhdfs/v1/. Reason:\n<pre>    Authentication required</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>
```

`[2021-07-15 12:01:30,948] {taskinstance.py:1128} ERROR - Read operations failed on the namenodes below:xxxxx`

Could you please let me know how to use this sensor as I dont find much information on how to use it. or please suggest any **alternative to check for the file arrival in hdfs**.
Thank you in advance for your reply.

Please find the code below:

```
source_data_sensor = WebHdfsSensor(
task_id='source_data_sensor',
filepath='filepath',
timeout=120,
webhdfs_conn_id='webhdfs_default',
poke_interval=10,
dag=dag,
env={
'JAVA_HOME': '/usr/bin/java'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs/stable/index.html): it needs `apache-airflow` version >=2.1.0 and `snakebite-py3`. Try installing `snakebite-py3` instead of `snakebite`, or just use `pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs` on top of Airflow 2.1+

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My current apache-airflow version is 1.10.9 :(